# Maven: add non-JAR dependency

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

I'am using the `maven-assembly-plugin` to create a `tar.gz` archive. Now I need to include files in that archive. These are just a bunch of plain old text files and are a dependency at runtime, not at compile or (unit) test time.

I thought about adding a maven dependency on that but these files are not stored in a maven repository but in a simple remove folder. To make it even worse, this folder is password protected. I could, in a pre-build-step, download these password-protected files into a local folder. But then there is still the problem of using those files in the assembly. Also, this is extra work I want to avoid.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: If you want to do is download files from a remote folder and zip them, why do you want to do that with maven?

Comment: @AssenKolov I want to include external files in the archive which is build, tested and packed with Maven.

Comment: You could publish your files as an assembly from the maven job and have a post-build step script that builds the final zip.

Answer (score 0):

If you can download those files, workaround password. Maybe this will help.
Create mod assembly project where you put something like that:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3"  
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">  
<id>${artifact.version}</id>  
<formats>
    <format>zip</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
        <useTransitiveDependencies>true</useTransitiveDependencies>
        <unpack>false</unpack>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>${project.groupId}:*:*</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <outputFileNameMapping>project${timestamp}_code-${artifact.name}.${artifact.extension}</outputFileNameMapping>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <includes>
            <include>readme.txt</include> <!-- here's that plain file -->
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

You can include those files in fileSets.
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/single/filtering-some-distribution-files.html for more info